# Conditional formating from one google sheet to another

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am working on a project and have a data reference sheet and a data studio presentation. I have a list of patient names in one column on the data sheet and a tag column as well as a column for "time".
I would like to be able to write "walk-in" in the tag column and write the time in the "time" column. Then ,on the data studio presentation i would like to create a "schedule" data box (7:30-5)and have the row with the tag "walk in" and the time in column "time" to show up in the right time slot on the data studio.

I was also wondering how to write something in one box on sheet 1 and have it show in another box on a second sheet.

This would help me so much! thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide an example sheet with what you have done so far, and what you want the result to be? I am not clear on what you are asking.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cpDqaxMxiVO3quC2ttYy15YrmvV2D07lj9_zleeCpzo/edit#gid=590402922

Comment: sheet one is the data set up i have and sheet two is what i would like to have by only updating sheet one

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cpDqaxMxiVO3quC2ttYy15YrmvV2D07lj9_zleeCpzo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand what you need, but by viewing the attached file, I guess that you ca build sheets2 as following, assuming you have B1=begin of period and B2=end if period

```
=query(Sheet1!A1:C,"SELECT B,C WHERE A='walk in' and C >= TIMEOFDAY '"&TEXT(B1,"HH:mm:ss")&"' and C <= TIMEOFDAY '"&TEXT(B2,"HH:mm:ss")&"' ")
```

Comment: thank you ! this helps. is there a way to have the times 7-5 written permanently on sheet 2 and have the corresponding times from sheet 1 pop up in the correct time slot? on sheet 2? I want to be able to visualize open time slots with sheet two

Comment: I have updated my answer to take your requirment into account

Comment: Hi thank you so much for taking the time! I'm very unfamiliar with google sheets so im not sure what you mean. I copy and pasted that function but kept getting error messages. I updated the sheet to show what I would like to have. sheet 1 is list of data not in order and sheet two is a schedule